# I have a div that constantly changes height. How can I get a second div to constantly adopt the height that the first div is?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that contains a list of items. The user is able to add to/remove items from the list, so the div constantly changes height to compensate for the changing size of the list.

I have another div to its right that is supposed to give details about the items on the left. How can I get the div on the right to constantly keep vertically aligned with the left div and change height so that it equals the height that the left div currently is, as items are added and removed from the left div's list?

Comment: One option is `display: table-cell` : http://jsfiddle.net/6by4wezw/

Comment: If you don't have to support legacy browsers (IE9 and below) then use flexbox.

Answer (score 3):

`display:table-cell` will help you here:

```css
div { display:table-cell; border:1px solid; }
```

```html
<div id=master>
  one<br>two
</div>
<div>
    three
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer your question without showing your code.  Try putting it in a fiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/

Here's what I would say.  Put your left and right divs into a container div, and then have the left and right div's inherit the containers height.

```
<div id="container" style="height:200px">
    <div style="float: left; height: 100%">
        list items<br />
        list items<br />
        list items
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; height: 100%; border: 1px solid black;">
        right div
    </div>
</div>
<br /><br />
<button onclick="document.getElementById('container').style.height='20px'" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove height from both of them, and wrap a div around both of them where you add the height.

Answer (score 1):

This function is called whenever something on the document changes, and it sets the height of div2 to the value for the height of div1

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
document.onchange=setDivHeight();
function setDivHeight(){
var x=Number(document.getElementById('1').style.height)
document.getElementById('2').style.height=x;
}
</script>
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
```

Comment: I really wanted to try implementing this solution, but something's wonky for me. Maybe because the script you wrote can't be used if it's place in the init.js file? http://jsfiddle.net/vnt83hz7/2/

Comment: @Sherri Thats odd. One thing that I noticed is that if you remove the Number() from the x value and leave only the element height, the div takes on the red background color

Answer (score 1):

**Flexbox Solution**

This answer is adapted from an example on [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) - Check it out

Assuming the following markup:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <article class="main">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  </article>
  <aside class="aside">
      <ul>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
  </ul>
 </aside>
</div>
```

We can create a flexbox that will force all columns to conform to the height of the largest with the following styles:

```
.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;  

  -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;

  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper > * {
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1 100%;
}

.main {
  text-align: left;
  background: deepskyblue;
  order: 2;
  flex: 3 0px;
}

.aside {
    background: gold;
    max-width: 200px;
    order: 1;
}

body {
  padding: 2em; 
}
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lrzy3c7L/1/)

**NOTE:** Browser support for this solution is limited to IE10+, and the use of browser prefixes still applies to most versions of major browsers.  For a more thorough breakdown of how flexbox works, I highly recommend that you check out the article I've linked to above.